# Symfony does not validate object constraints

Tags: forms, validation, symfony, constraints, silex

I have a Silex project where i use the FormServiceProvider and ValidatorServiceProvider. I have made a form with the form.factory builder, added fields, and use an object as dataset:

```
$form = $app['form.factory']->createBuilder('form', $object)
```

I then try to validate the form on submition the "normal way":

```
if ($app['request']->getMethod() == 'POST') {
    $form->bind($app['request']);
    if ($form->isValid()) {
        (...)
    }
}
```

In the object, i have added a loadValidatorMetadata static method:

```
static public function loadValidatorMetadata(ClassMetadata $metadata) {
    $metadata->addPropertyConstraint('name', new Assert\MinLength(5, array('message' => 'Name too short')));
}
```

When I submit the form with a shorter name field, isValid still return true. If I run a validate method on the object like this:

```
$errors = $app['validator']->validate($object)
```

it returns an error based on the constraint, but the form isValid does not find this error. When i looked into the symfony Form class, i found that isValid skips checking child fields when the disable config is true. This is the case for my form, but I have no idea why. I have just registered the Silex service providers the normal way without any special config. Any idea how to make the form fail validation based on the object constraints?

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to be working fine in my Silex setup. Maybe you just needed to call the `$form->handleRequest()` method?

**Controller**

```
$app->match('/form', function (Request $request) use ($app) {

    $object = new \My\Namespaced\Entity\Object();

    $form = $app['form.factory']->createBuilder('form', $object)
        ->add('name')
        ->add('submit', 'submit')
        ->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $app['session']->getFlashBag()->add('success', 'Success flash message');
    }
    else {
        $app['session']->getFlashBag()->add('danger', 'Error flash message');
    }

    return new Response($app['twig']->render('form.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    )));   

})->bind('form');
```

**Object Class**

```
<?php

namespace My\Namespaced\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Mapping\ClassMetadata;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class Object 
{
    private $name;

    static public function loadValidatorMetadata(ClassMetadata $metadata) {
        $metadata->addPropertyConstraint('name', new Assert\Length(array(
            'min' => 5,
            'minMessage' => 'Name too short',
        )))
        ->addPropertyConstraint('name', new Assert\NotBlank(array(
            'message' => 'Name is required field.'
        )));
    }

    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

**Twig Template**

```
{% extends 'layout.html.twig' %}
{% block content %}
    {{ form(form, {action: path('form'), attr:{ 'novalidate': 'novalidate' }}) }}
{% endblock %}
```